# Bash script (OS X) check running process, quit if running, BUT start if not (On/Off)

Tags: macos, bash, process

I looking to have a script, inside a .app (using Platypus or something) that can check a running process with something like pgrep and handle the output by running the process if it isn't already running but killing it if it is (pkill or something).

The kill would need to stop the process that the script started first time round plus the app that it ran from in the first place.

I know this isn't right but something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
if pgrep 'process' &> /dev/null;
then     'command';
else pkill "command,app" || true;
fi
```

Comment: Instead of simply killing a process by name, a more reliable way would be to save the PID of the process once you start, to a file or something. Then while killing you typically do atleast 2 checks: existence of the file and a valid PID in it, and existence of process with an appropriate name. This is so that you dont kill another instance by mistake.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How would I go about this? It's essentially a script that needs to turn off and on each time it's run. I have incorporated the right processes to run and to close in two separate scripts. I just need a script now that will run one or run the other if it sees an instance of a process.